# "You can no longer edit this comment" is misleading

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comment-edits

When attempting to edit a comment before the time-out is finished, I get a message "You can no longer edit this comment". Why not state the 5min timeout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good idea; there are several reasons you might get this message but that should be the most common form. Implemented.

Comment: I think the wording could be improved here.  Right now it says, "comments may only be edited for 5 minutes."  I think it would be better stating: "comments may only be edited within the first 5 minutes of posting."

Comment: Completely agree with Jeff. I just got this message and had no idea what it meant until I saw his post. Had I been editing the comment for more than 5 minutes? Do I have to wait 5 minutes before editing a comment? Those were my first two thoughts, but neither of them is correct according to the above interpretation. How about, "Sorry, after 5 minutes, you may no longer edit a comment." Simple, to the point.