# Deleting feature requests for implemented trivial issues

Tags: discussion, meta

There is a case where I had a [trivial feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69641/you-can-no-longer-edit-this-comment-is-misleading), the sort that didn't gather any discussion. Now, I'm wondering about its value at all. Does it make sense to delete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has value in that others see we listen to feedback and implement reasonable suggestions.

As for its lasting value, it will float off the bottom of the list in due time and become part of the historical record of "things we have completed".

Comment: Too quick your answer :-) Thanks a lot, makes sense.

Comment: I have just finished watching "Man from Earth". That fact makes your second paragraph really deep. Movies can really screw with your mind...

Comment: @tshe the only time I delete old requests is when they become so out of date that accidentally "discovering" them would be confusing at best. Depends on the request though.